# How do I create a customized ISO of Ubuntu that can be installed on multiple systems, a la OEM configuration?

Tags: iso, custom-distributions, oem

I am working on created a customized version of Ubuntu (with certain NEEDED customizations) that will, aftewards, need to be installed on others computers. I know about OEM install, but how do I customize the ISO with the packages and setup files I need?

Comment: An alternative is to look like what you would do if system drive crashed & you have to do a new install & restore from your backup? You copy /home back & restore list of installed apps. If server type apps or setting you may need some settings from /etc or other system folders which those that use server know how to backup. I script a lot of my changes as I typically do not want to restore /home in a test install as I want different settings. If full image: http://clonezilla.org/ & backups: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools

Comment: What I need to do involves editing xubuntu UI and a bunch of other things. I am working on creating a kid-friendly iso that parents can dual boot and have their kids be safe within. This involves a lot of stuff that needs to be done through the OEM environment, through GUI, because it would be incredibly difficult to do through terminal.

Comment: You can [Preseed](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed) Debian.  Ubuntu has [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs02.html) specific to Preseeding Ubuntu.  You can set up a [PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) server with this custom image to allow installation over the network.

Comment: This isn't that. An example of the sort of stuff I want to do is install firefox and set its theme, add a firewall to it, Change the user interface to make it simpler for children, set up themes, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: That solution wont work as ubuntu builder is no more and doesnt fit what I want in the first place